# Infopath 2010 - Browser based form with custom dialogs?

Tags: infopath

is it possible to tap into SP2010's dialog framework from a web-based InfoPath form? If not, can one override FormServer.aspx to use custom dialogs?

Please advise, thank you!

Cheers,
Bob

Comment: What dialogs are you talking about? You can publish any InfoPath form as a list form or as a regular form template and the forms will be shown in SP2010.

Comment: I have a fully functional InfoPath form that is being rendered in SP. But what I want to do is access the client side javascript api from the form but I don't know how.

For example, at it's simplest, how would I insert a call to window.open() in FormCode.cs?  

Also, SP2010 has a full js library (SP.UI.Dialog.js) that I would like to access but I don't know how.

One of my requirements is to offer a non-modal help window that a user can follow while filling out the form, but I don't get how I can do this from InfoPath.

Any idea? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no control in InfoPath for JavaScript. If by chance you are able to use the form in the new InfoPath Web Part rather than as the content type in a form library, then you may be able to insert some JavaScript (jQuery) in a separate Content Editor Web Part on the same page to accomplish what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Thanks Rob! I'm intrigued by your suggestion to use an InfoPath webpart. I'll have to research more about that.